# Excel Advanced filtering using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Basically every week I get an excel containing resource list which has same headers.

[image: Excel resource list]

Most of us use this excel and according to below criteria filter that excel and copy results in another sheet.

[image: Filter Criteria]

I am developing an tool which asks user to open the specific excel and then according to filter criteria display the results below. Below is the code I have manged to write on my own.

```
Public currentWB As Workbook
Public dataWB As Workbook
Sub FilterData()

    Dim strFileToOpen As String

    strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
    FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

    If strFileToOpen = Null Then
        MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set currentWB = ActiveWorkbook

        Sheets("Filter").Select
        Range("A14").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Clear

        Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen, UpdateLinks:=False

        Set dataWB = ActiveWorkbook

            dataWB.Sheets(2).Range("A2:EA15000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:= _
            currentWB.Sheets("Master").Range("A1:F2"), CopyToRange:=currentWB.Sheets("Filter").Range("A14"), Unique:=True
        Columns.AutoFit
        dataWB.Close False
        Range("A14").Select
    End If

End Sub
```

The filter criteria can only have specific inputs so I created drop-down and the values come from another sheet called "master".

My code works but it's not giving me the right data. How to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not giving the right data'? Do you get the right data if you do the steps manually? Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: is there any reason why you can't get the resource list file in your macro file (or link to it via Excel Data Connections) and use a Pivot Table to do the filtering? May be a lot easier and less reliant on VBA. Or at most you can just use VBA to update the master file each week and the Pivot Table will auto refresh with a dynamic named range.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman every week we get a new file for the resource list. I didn't think that the objective could be achieved without code. I will try to do that and come back if I ran into any issue.

Comment: @vacip some how I am getting data which doesn't even exist in the sheet. I have debugged the code but filter copy and paste is done in single line so it isn't helping me.